# rich:scrollableDataTable causing infinite posting loop

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm getting some very strange behavior from a new scrollableDataTable component I'm trying to add. I have stripped its attributes and content down to the bare minimum and the odd behavior continues.

So the problem is: When I hit the page that includes the file with my scrollable data table (Which is in a Modal window), the page seems to go on an endless submitting/re-rendering loop. As if it just keeps re-rendering the entire page or submitting the page.

My code is attached.

I'm using Richfaces 3.3.1 and JSF 2.0.4.

main.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
    <ui:composition template="/templates/mclayout.xhtml">

<ui:define name="body">
    <rich:modalPanel id="mpDetail" minHeight="550" minWidth="480" zindex="2000">
        <a4j:form id="detail">
            <ui:include src="includeFile1.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="show1" value="#{myBean.struct.item.value}" />
            </ui:include>
```

includeFile1.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">

    <rich:tabPanel id="my_tabpanel" value="#{myBean.selectedTab}" selectedTab="#{myBean.selectedTab}" switchType="client">

    <rich:tab id="hTest" label="test">
        <ui:include src="test-details-tab.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="testBean" value="#{myBean}" />
        </ui:include>
    </rich:tab>
```

test-details-tab.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">

    <rich:scrollableDataTable id="testID">

    </rich:scrollableDataTable>

</html>
```

### Edit

Looking at my eclipse tomcat logs I can see that it is in fact re-rendering the page 2 times per second on average.

### Edit 2

Ok, so I've tried a very simple example in its own single seperate page. It is still not working, the endless resubmitting/looping is still occuring.
I also put an editor component in, just to make sure it was not Richfaces 3.3 on my system....the editor works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
    <ui:composition template="/templates/mclayout.xhtml">


        <ui:define name="pageTitle">
            <h:outputFormat value="#{messages['page_title']}" />
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="heading">
            #{messages[componentNavigator.currentComponent.id]}
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="body">


                <h:form id="form">
                    <h:panelGroup style="height:320px;width:400px;" layout="block">
                        <rich:editor id="editor" width="400" height="300"></rich:editor>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:form>

                <h:form id="form2">
                    <rich:spacer height="30" />
                    <h:panelGroup style="height:320px;width:400px;" layout="block">
                        <rich:scrollableDataTable height="400px" width="700px" id="carList">
                            <rich:column id="make">
                                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="Make" /></f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column id="model">
                                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="Model" /></f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </rich:column>
                        </rich:scrollableDataTable>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <rich:spacer height="20px"/>
                </h:form>

        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

### Edit 3

It turns out the version of JSF running is 1.2

Is it possible that this is the cause of the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What if you put this all in a single facelet instead of a bunch of includes? I'd imagine that it is not designed to be used this way.

Comment: Ok, I took it out and put it outside the ModalPanel in main.xhtml to test this out. No more infinite loop this way. Is there some way around this? Surely ModalPanels can accept table components?

Comment: I have no idea. I am not that familiar with RichFaces.